prove a property about absolutely continuous function
Suppose $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R},f \ is \ absolutely \ continuous \ function,$
Prove:$$If  \ m(Z)=0,then \ m[f(Z)]=0,"m" \ denotes \ the \  Lebesgue  \ measure,Z\subseteq[a,b] $$(I am not sure it is true)
I know that f is uniformly continuous function and f is bound variation function.But I don't know how to use "absolute continuity"to prove this proposition.
